# updating multiple reference mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update `multiple references` in mongodb and mongoose.

```
Team.update({_id: {$in: players.team}},
          {$addToSet: {players: player._id}},{multi: true},function(err,numberAffected){

});
```

My Team model has a `players` array which contains a lot of `team ids`. I am trying to update my each `team` field `players` with new `players` id. The above query is failing and its not `updating multiple document`.

Comment: Can you please check the following:

1) You probably meant that team model has a players array which contains a lot of players ids (not team ids)?

2) What is the players.team in your query ({_id: {$in: players.team}})? Are you sure it is an array of team ids? Make sure you actually receive teams you are trying to update on this query:

Team.find({_id: {$in: players.team}})
3) What does it mean 'query is failing', can you provide the error you receive?

Thanks

Comment: please provide your schema and exmaple data.